# Laço de repetição JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loop, switch

Estou tentando fazer uma "mini batalha pokemon", porém, gostaria de adicionar alguma mensagem de invalidez caso a opção desejada seja a incorreta. Qual estrutura devo utilizar para que ele me retorne um alerta e volte a tela de seleção?
Outra dúvida, no switch aninhado dentro de cada opção de pokemon, haveria a opção de prosseguir com a escolha e ir a batalha ou desistir da opção e retornar ao menu de seleção, porém não consigo fazer com que escolhendo a opção de retornar ao menu de seleção ele volte a escolha dos pokemons.

```
function chosenMenu() {
    let chosenOption
    while (chosenOption != "1" && chosenOption != "2" && chosenOption != "3") {
        chosenOption = prompt("Qual Pokémon deseja escolher?\n\n1- Charmander\n2- Bulbassaur\n3- Squirtle")
    }
    return chosenOption
}

function charmander(){
    prompt("Vida: " + 50 + "\nDano: " + 50 + "\nCura: " + 50 + "\n\nDeseja realmente escolher este Pokémon?\n\n1- Sim\n2- Não")
}

function bulbassaur(){
    prompt("Vida: " + 50 + "\nDano: " + 50 + "\nCura: " + 50 + "\n\nDeseja realmente escolher este Pokémon?\n\n1- Sim\n2- Não")
}

function squirtle(){
    prompt("Vida: " + 50 + "\nDano: " + 50 + "\nCura: " + 50 + "\n\nDeseja realmente escolher este Pokémon?\n\n1- Sim\n2- Não")
}

function batalha() {
    alert("A batalha irá começar!")
}

chosenOption = chosenMenu()
let confirmPokemon = ""

switch(chosenOption) {
    case "1":
        charmander()
            switch(chosenOption) {
                case "1":
                    batalha()
                    break
                case "2":  
                alert("Voltando a tela de escolha Pokémon")
                    break      
                }
    break
    
    case "2":
        bulbassaur()
            switch(chosenOption) {
            case "1":
                batalha()
                break
            case "2":
                alert("Voltando a tela de escolha Pokémon")
                break
            }
    break
    
    case "3":
        squirtle()
            switch(chosenOption) {
                case "1":
                    batalha()
                    break
                case "2":
                    alert("Voltando a tela de escolha Pokémon")
                    break  
            }
    break
    default: 
        alert("") 
        break      
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Bom no momento foquei apenas na exibição da mensagem de opção invalida no menu

para isso eu criei uma função chamada errormenssage()

ela é construida desta maneira

```
function errormenssage(){
    alert("Opção invalida, retornando ao menu!")
}
```

Bom para chamar a mensagem de erro quando o usuario não digita uma opção valida no menu
eu precisei colocar um if dentro do while, o chosenMenu() ficou desta maneira

```
///// INICIO DO chosenMenu()

function chosenMenu() {
    let chosenOption = prompt("Qual Pokémon deseja escolher?\n\n1- Charmander\n2- Bulbassaur\n3- Squirtle")
    
    while (chosenOption != "1" && chosenOption != "2" && chosenOption != "3") {
            chosenOption = prompt("Qual Pokémon deseja escolher?\n\n1- Charmander\n2- Bulbassaur\n3- Squirtle")

     if (chosenOption != "1" && chosenOption != "2" && chosenOption != "3") {
            errormenssage()
            }
    }
   return  chosenOption
    
}
//// FIM DO chosenMenu()
```

o if dentro do while ta fazendo com que ele seja executado apenas se a opção não seja valida, coloquei ele embaixo do prompt
para que a mensagem de opção invalida  não apareça antes do menu

(Sou apenas um estudante não sei se o if dentro do while é melhor maneira, ou se criar uma function especifica pra mensagem de erro seja o correto)

Para tudo funcionar corretamente tive que alterar o switch
chamando apenas a função principal

No caso o switch ficou assim:

```
switch(chosenOption) {
    case "1":
    charmander()
    break
    case "2":
    bulbassaur()
    break
    case "3":
    squirtle()
    break
    default:
    alert("Opção invalida")
}
```

E por ultimo para fazer com que a opção 2 leve o usuario ao menu tive que armazenar os prompt de cada função
dentro da variavel ConfirmPokemon

cada função ficou assim:

```
function charmander(){
    let confirmPokemon = prompt("Vida: " + 50 + "\nDano: " + 50 + "\nCura: " + 50 + "\n\nDeseja realmente escolher este Pokémon?\n\n1- Sim\n2- Não")
   
   if(confirmPokemon == "1"){
         batalha()
     }if(confirmPokemon == "2"){
         alert("Voltando a tela de escolha Pokémon")
         chosenMenu()
     }
     return confirmPokemon 
}
```

O codigo até então não apresenta erro no console, porém está acontecendo um erro que quando o usuario escolhe a opção dentro da função chamada no caso a charmander()
Em seguida o usuario volta para o menu;
O menu aparece ao usuario porém quando ele  executa o comando no menu ele simplesmente some e não reexecuta o codigo, Bom travei nessa parte, no futuro tentarei outra solução!

o resultado é esse

codigo completo:  https://pastebin.com/GRZD5u3e

Comment: Texto do AR: *"...Alias é minha primera resposta no stackOverFlow, por algum motivo, ele está removendo os espaços. Então coloquei o codigo completo no pastebin...."*